# Javascript converting string to number only if the string is an number

Tags: javascript

How can I convert string to a number if I don't know if the string value is a valid number or not. I want to leave the string as is if it is not valid.

**Example**

```
"0" -> 0
"0.5" -> 0.5
"100" -> 100
"abc" -> "abc" //  remains a string
" " -> " " // remains an empty string
"-1" -> -1 // I'd like to convert negative numbers too
```

I've tried

```
var str = " ";
var num = +str // num = 0
var num = Number(str) // num = 0
var num = parseInt(str) // num = NaN
```

So seems my problem is with space. I was thinking of using `parseInt` but I thought that it might be a bad idea to use `NaN` as a value in Javascript and just leaving the string as is would be better.

Comment: Create a custom function that will use `parseInt`. If the result is `NaN` you return the string

Comment: you can add a simple `if` condition. no?

Comment: `0.5` isn't an int...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if the stringed numerical value is equal to the value.

```js
var array = ["0", "0.5", "100", "abc", " "];

console.log(array.map(a => (+a).toString() === a ? +a : a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Das ist wunderbar, danke!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom function

```js
function customParseInt(str) {
  const parsed = +str;
  return str.trim()==="" ? str : isNaN(parsed) ? str : parsed;
}

console.log(customParseInt("0"));
console.log(customParseInt("0.5"));
console.log(customParseInt("100"));
console.log(customParseInt("abc"));
console.log(customParseInt(" "));
console.log(customParseInt("5ab"));
console.log(customParseInt("-1"));
```

Comment: @RobG OP did not give details about scientific notation

Comment: OP doesn't even distinguish between a Float and an Int (question asks for int, but then uses 0.5 as an example).

Comment: @Weedoze use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` .its parse the floating value also

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "";
var num = isNaN( Number(str) ) ? str : Number(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some simple checking first, then use the `Number(x)` as it will handle decimal point numbers and more. `parseInt` only deals with, as the name implies, integers.

Here is an example.

```
function toNumberIfNumber(convertee) {
  const prep = convertee.trim();
  if (prep === "") {
      return convertee;
  }

  const num = Number(convertee);
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    return convertee;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}

console.log(toNumberIfNumber("0"));   //0
console.log(toNumberIfNumber("0.5")); //0.5
console.log(toNumberIfNumber("100")); //100
console.log(toNumberIfNumber("abc")); //"abc"
console.log(toNumberIfNumber(" "));   //" "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `==` to check if the converted int and the string are same.

for example you have 2 strings

```
var a = '123', b = '111x';
var intA = parseInt(a), intB = parseInt(b);
if(a == intA){
    console.log(a is a valid integer string); // this gets printed
}else{
    console.log('a is not a valid integer string');
}

if(b == intB){
    console.log(b is a valid integer string); 
}else{
    console.log('b is not a valid integer string');// this gets printed
}
```

Comment: using == versus === should be avoided.

Comment: Also, when using parseInt, always use Radix... https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @VedranMaricevic `==` should be avoided only when type coercion is not understood.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of '||' operator like below

var num = parseInt(str) || num;

It will return integer equivalent of 'str' if valid otherwise leaves it as it is.

Comment: won't it just remain a string if num = "0"?